# Is it possible to waste too many access cards on XP bonuses?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

It looks like you get one Access Card per level, and you can use these on various things in the armory. There's a clearly set number of things to unlock (once unlocked, they're unlocked), and there're a few temporary XP bonuses that you can spend these cards on to earn more faster. Since there is an achievement for level 100, I'm assuming that's the maximum level you can reach (please correct me if I'm wrong on that), which would suggest a limit on the number of access cards you can get. If there is a limit, then if you spend too many on XP bonuses, you won't be able to unlock everything.

Is there a finite number of access cards available? Is it possible to waste so many on XP bonuses that it's impossible to unlock everything in the armory? If so, what's the limit? How can I tell if I've wasted too many, or if it's still safe to spend them on XP bonuses?

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't vary by platform, but if it does, I'm asking from an Xbox 360 perspective

Comment: You can edit your question instead of adding a commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant information from [xboxachievements](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/injustice-gods-among-us/achievement/77029-Hoarder.html) and confirmed by other sources states:

> In total, you will need 84 Access Cards and 24 Armory Keys to unlock everything in the Archives. After Level 50, every time you unlock an Access Card, you will be given two. Furthermore, after Level 75, you will be given 3 Access Cards per level. If you don't use any Cards on Bonus XP, you will have enough Cards by Level 68.

From my investigation, the number does not appear to be clearly finite because there are several people well above level 100 indicating the level 100 is not a maximum (I read of someone over level 500).

### Did you waste Access Cards?

While you don't appear to have prevented yourself from fully unlocking the armory, you may have delayed unlocking the armory because the XP grind at higher levels for the consequent access cards becomes much steeper. There's probably a balance that can be calculated based on how much XP the XP boost actually buys you versus the added XP grind of the higher level now needed to replace the cards spent.

In the end, it really depends how high a level you want to reach. **If you were going to go for level 100 anyways, then you're probably fine.** That's ~165 access cards by lv.100 and you need 84 for unlocks, leaving you with ~80 cards to spend how you like. 84 cards are gained at levels 71-100 so there's lots of headroom if you'd rather do the armory at the end of your grind. As long as the XP your bonuses are buying is equal and you were grinding that high anyway, there's no balance to strike and there's no waste. As far as striking the most efficient use of XP bonuses, that's really a separate question.